# Magento 2: How to add footer in pdf invoice?

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

**How to add store information and terms and conditions inside pdf invoice file in magento 2?**

Also how to add footer in each page of pdf in magento 2 invoice pages?

Comment: https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For pdf,

- **Pdf Starts Calculation from Bottom-Left Corner of Page and by default is measured in points. Start with X and Y axis at left bottom
  page.**

  We have to set based on our requirements set $this->x and $this->y axis.

> Page size can be retrieved from a page object's get widht and height function,
>   using $page object:

**//start with zend_pdf method of zend frameworks,**

```
$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
$this->_setPdf($pdf);
```

**//create new page in pdf**

```
$page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
```

**//set color**

```
$page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

**//set font**

```
$page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 8);
```

**//set stye for pdf,**

```
$style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
```

**//set bold font**

```
$this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

$page->drawText($title, 225, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

Page Height and widht for pdf,

```
 SIZE_A4                = '595:842:';
    SIZE_A4_LANDSCAPE      = '842:595:';
    SIZE_LETTER            = '612:792:';
    SIZE_LETTER_LANDSCAPE  = '792:612:';
```

**//get page widht**

```
$width  = $page->getWidth(); //width for A4 page, 595
```

**//get page height**

```
$height = $page->getHeight(); //Height for A4 page,842
```

**//write text into pdf,**

```
$this->x = 30;
$this->y = 800;
$page->drawText('This is test example', $this->x, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

*Override invoice php file for invoice pdf customization,*
**Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice,**

```
class Invoicepdf extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice{
     public function getPdf($invoices = [])
        {       
            //custom code of getpdf

                //add new footer section this is our custom code function...
                $this->_drawFooter($page);   

             $this->_afterGetPdf();
             return $pdf;
        }

        protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {
            $this->y =50;    
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(1, 1, 1));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(60, $this->y, 510, $this->y -30);

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
            $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 7);
            $this->y -=10;
            $page->drawText("Company name", 70, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText("Tel: +123 456 676", 230, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText("Registered in Countryname", 430, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        }
}
```

Comment: I've created something similar using this as inspiration. However, when printing several orders off in one go, the Footer only appears on the last page. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @rakesh,have you any idea how to update text fonts?

Comment: Hello @rakesh,can you please check my above query ?

Answer (score 3):

The x and y coordinate in Pdf aren't easy, we should calcuate by ourself.

First of all, we need to override the `getPdf` method of Invoice Pdf

*Module/Vendor/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php*

```
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
 {
    ......
    $this->insertStoreInformation($page);

    ......

    $this->insertFooterInvoice($page);
    ......
 }
```

Second, build our methods:

```
public function insertStoreInformation(&$page)
 {
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $font = $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setLineWidth(0);
    $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;

    $storeName =$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/name',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );

    //Draw store name
    if($storeName) {
        foreach ($this->string->split($storeName, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(
                        trim(strip_tags($_value)),
                        $this->getAlignRight($_value, 130, 440, $font, 10),
                        $top,
                        'UTF-8'
                    );
                    $top -= 10;
                }
    }

    $this->y = $this->y > $top ? $top : $this->y;

 }

 public function insertFooterInvoice(&$page)
 {
    $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 100;
    $text = 'Footer Invoice';
    //Draw store name
    if($text) {
        foreach ($this->string->split($text, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(
                        trim(strip_tags($_value)),
                        $this->getAlignRight($_value, 130, 440, $font, 10),
                        $top,
                        'UTF-8'
                    );
                    $top -= 10;
                }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on magento current version i.e. Magento2.6.The `getPdf` function is slightly changed.It has private variable `$this->appEmulation` due to this limitation we can't use preference to rewrite full file.

Based on it we can append footer using below code.

You can achieve this by using a plugin for the `getPdf()` method. Here's an updated example:

1. Create a custom module if you haven't already done so.
2. Create a di.xml file in your module's etc directory: `app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/di.xml.`
3. Add the plugin configuration in the di.xml file to specify your plugin class:

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice">
       <plugin name="your_plugin_name" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Sales\Order\Pdf\InvoicePlugin"
               sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
   </type>
   ```
4. Create the plugin class InvoicePlugin.php in the directory app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Plugin/Sales/Order/Pdf:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Sales\Order\Pdf;

   class InvoicePlugin
   {

   public function aroundGetPdf(
       \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice $subject,
       \Closure $proceed,
       $invoices = []
   ) {
       // Call the original method to generate the invoice PDF
       $pdf = $proceed($invoices);

       // Add footer to each page of the PDF
       foreach ($pdf->pages as $page) {
           $this->addFooterToPage($page);
       }

       return $pdf;
   }


   protected function addFooterToPage($page)
   {
       // Set font style for the footer
       $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
       $page->setFont($font, 10);

       // Set footer text and position
       $footerText = __('Your Footer Text Here');
       $footerPosition = 50; // Adjust the position as needed

       // Draw the footer
       $page->drawText($footerText, 25, $footerPosition, 'UTF-8'); 
     }
   }
   ```